# Is 80% of a human's sense of taste in their nose?

Tags: nutrition, smell, taste

According to [this article on wine tasting](http://whatscookingamerica.net/Information/WineTasting.htm):

> Did you know that 80% of our sense of taste is actually in our nose?

It doesn't seem to cite any source, although I've heard similar claims before.  I've also experienced first-hand anecdotal evidence that holding my nose reduces the sensation of taste when eating.  But I've also heard (I can't find sources now) that these claims are largely exaggerated.

What do *actual studies* say the relationship is between a human's sense of smell and taste?

Comment: Also, when you have a bad cold you can't really taste food.

Comment: Note that while a number like *"80%"* presents a sense of rigid scientific measurement, it is almost certainly completely made up (author [Charles Seife](http://www.amazon.com/Proofiness-Dark-Arts-Mathematical-Deception/dp/0670022160) calls these "potemkin numbers").  There really is no way to quantify taste due to either smell or tastebuds - the best we could say is that it's due *more* to smell or tastebuds.

Comment: Also: See [The Drunkard's Walk](http://www.amazon.com/Drunkards-Walk-Randomness-Rules-Lives/dp/0375424040) for more examples like this related to wine-tasting (the author is an avid wine-taster).  You'll be surprised how little the ratings printed on wine bottles mean!

Comment: @Blue - "hold your nose and eat something". You now owe me an ambulance call fee <g>

Comment: Anecdotally my mother lost her entire sense of smell and can no longer taste anything except the basic sweet, salty, bitter, etc.

Comment: I think there probably is quite a bit of research on this but it is liable to be secured behind trade secret type walls.  I have heard there is a scientific process that goes into designing new food products.  If this is true then I am guessing someone might be able to access some of the data or at least some paper or trade show type lecture.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPlughoeft: That's not a good test: your mouth and your nose are connected. In fact, it is because they are connected that smell influences taste.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft The term "Potemkin" is derived from largely bogus claims that fake villages were created to impress Empress Catherine II of Russia. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potemkin_village

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is important not to confuse taste with flavor. Taste is a sense perceived by special cells that constitute taste buds. When most people use the word taste they are referring to flavor, which is a combination of multiple senses.

> Flavor is what people commonly call the "taste" of food. It is
>   actually a combination of smell, taste, spiciness, temperature and
>   texture. Much of the flavor of food comes from smell, so that when you
>   are unable to smell you have lost much of your ability to experience
>   flavor. -[Source](http://uconntasteandsmell.uchc.edu/facts/index.html)

In interpreting flavor the brain takes into account not only taste and smell, but also touch and heat[[1]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flavor). With spicy food pain is [even a factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piquancy) for flavor.

So, in answer to the title question, no, ~80% of taste is not in the nose, no amount of taste is influenced by smell. Smell is indeed the primary determinate for flavor. I can't find a specific authoritative source for this, however the claim appears repeated in several reputable sources:

> Flavor defines the food that is eaten, and is recognized mainly
>   through the sense of smell.-[Source](http://www.utsouthwestern.edu/patientcare/healthlibrary/smell_and_taste_disorders__chemosensory_disorders_/0,,P00466,00.html)

> Researchers say 80 percent of the flavors we taste come from what we
>   smell, which is why foods become relatively flavorless when we're
>   plugged up. -[Source](http://www.livescience.com/10457-smell.html)

> It surprised me to read, when I began my research, that about 90% of
>   what we believe to be taste is really due to smell. -[Source](http://serendip.brynmawr.edu/exchange/node/1575)

> According to Dr Alan Hirsch of the Taste Treatment and Research
>   Foundation in Chicago, 90% of what is perceived as taste is actually
>   smell. -[Source](http://www.guardian.co.uk/lifeandstyle/wordofmouth/2008/jul/21/anosmiasensetaste)

It seems fair to say that yes, smell accounts for somewhere around 80% of flavor (taste).

Comment: Thank you for making the excellent distinction between *taste* and *flavor*!